# accessing facebook app with app token

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, token, access-token

I have a little issue getting access to some ad data via an app

I have these two scripts:

Login

```
<?php


    include_once __DIR__ . '/includes/connect.php';
    require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

    use Facebook\Facebook;

    session_start();

    $facebook = new Facebook([
        'app_id' => 'XXX',
        'app_secret' => 'XXX',
        'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5',
        ]);

    $helper = $facebook->getRedirectLoginHelper();

    $permissions = ['ads_read'];
    $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('http://sparnorddashboard.local:8080/fb_callback.php', $permissions);

    echo '<a href="'.  $loginUrl .'">Log ind</a>';

?>
```

Callback

```
<?php
include_once __DIR__ . '/includes/connect.php';
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use Facebook\Facebook;

session_start();

$facebook = new Facebook([
    'app_id' => 'XXX',
    'app_secret' => 'XXX',
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5',
    ]);

$helper = $facebook->getRedirectLoginHelper();

try {

    $access_token = $helper->getAccessToken();


} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}

if(!isset($access_token)) {

    if($helper->getError()) {

        header("HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized");

        echo "Error: " . $helper->getError() . "\n";
        echo "Error Code: " . $helper->getErrorCode() . "\n";
        echo "Error Reason: " . $helper->getErrorReason() . "\n";
        echo "Error Description: " . $helper->getErrorDescription() . "\n";

    } else {

        header('HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request');
        echo 'Bad request';

    }

    exit;   

}

$oAuth2Client = $facebook->getOAuth2Client();
$tokenMetaData = $oAuth2Client->debugToken($access_token);

$tokenMetaData->validateAppId("1694068770828491");
$tokenMetaData->validateExpiration();


if(!$access_token->isLongLived()) {

    try {

        $access_token = $oAuth2Client->getLongLivedAccessToken($access_token);

    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {

        $e->getMessage();
        exit;

    }

}

$_SESSION['fb_access_token'] = (string) $access_token;

header('Location: http://sparnorddashboard.local:8080/fetchads.php?callback=callback');

?>
```

But this will use the user client token - How can I set it up so that I can us the app access token? I don't want a user to login and accept permissions, as  this is for a internal dashboard, that runs on a TV moniter, that will read ads data - nothing else.

Comment: AFAIK you can not use your app token for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use your APP access token for `ads_read`. If you don't want to get it via user login, then another way is to get via Graph Api Explorer.

**Assuming you already created an [Ad Account](https://www.facebook.com/ads/manager/)** :

1. Login to [Graph Api Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/).
2. Change to your App.
   [image]
3. Click 'Get Token' and then 'Get User Access Token'
   [image]
4. Click 'Extended Permissions' tab and check `ads_read` and click Get Access Token.
   [image]
5. Grant yourself the permissions you requested.
   [image]
6. Use the user access token that will be presented to you in the access token form input field:
   [image]

---

Use the generated access token for your internal dashboard app/script, e.g:

```
// Add to header of your file
use FacebookAds\Api;

// Initialize a new Session and instantiate an Api object
Api::init(
  '{your-app-id}',
  '{your-app-secret}',
  $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] // The generated access token
);
```

Comment: I am getting "Invalid appsecret_proof provided in the API argument"

Comment: @MortenHagh I edited the answer. In the Graph Api Explorer you must change to your APP (added step) not as Graph Api Explorer.

Comment: How long does this token live ?

Comment: @MortenHagh There is no mention about token expiration from the manual, even if it will expired, **probably** in 60 days.